# How to open .etl.z file ? Its 'OneDrive for Business' log files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

Recently we faced an issue when a user try to sync with SharePoint using OneDrive.

After googling, I found the OneDrive logs are present in the SPW folder 
https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/279832

But It is **.ETL.Z** format.

I tried to open with Event Viewer, But it doesn't works.

How to open **.etl.z** file? Its 'OneDrive for Business' log files

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following question I recently asked on MS site: [OneDrive for Business log files](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/p/419861/1052278#1052278).

Looks like despite of `*.etl` extension this files are packed with specific archiver which can be opened by MS staff only (but I haven't done deeper research)